# PowerShell - Getting Return Value From Script Run on Remote Machine?

Tags: powershell, server

I'm just trying to get a script on a local machine run on a remote machine and have a result returned back to the local caller. What am I doing wrong? This is almost verbatim one of several examples I've seen, except they used -ScriptBlock {} to do it. Is this just not possible to achieve using the -FilePath option? I double-checked the local path. Both of the scripts are in the same folder on the same drive on the local machine.

This Caller gives me a blank result.

Local Caller:

```
Write-Output "Retrieving results from server call."
$returned=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $MyCredential -FilePath D:\scripts\runOnRemote.ps1
Write-Output $returned
```

The following produces 'DummyMessage' as expected

Alternate Local Caller:

```
$returned=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $MyCredential -ScriptBlock {

        $toReturn = 'DummyMessage'
        return $toReturn
    }
```

But this doesn't.
Script trying to run on remote:

```
$returnMessage = 'DummyMessage'
return $returnMessage
```

Output:

```
Retrieving results from server call.
<nothing>
```

Vs.

```
Retrieving results from server call.
DummyMessage
```

Comment: I tried this example and it works for me.

Comment: I forgot to update this yesterday. It looks like Microsoft's ISE just randomly stops reinterpreting revisions and just runs old code. Maybe this is a problem of still being stuck on Windows 7, but idk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after returning from lunch. It was an ISE bug that just wasn't interpreting new code revisions after so many runs (hence my confusion!).